# Flutter) How to count to specific values inside map

Tags: flutter, dictionary, count

I have a map looks like this

```dart
 Map<String, String> vaccinated = {
    'dog': 'ready',
    'cat': 'ready',
    'mouse': 'done',
    'horse': 'done',
  };
```

and I would like to count only 'done' inside the map and wants a result of

```
2
```

but the thing I've tried showed me is only boolean
anyone knows how can I count specific values inside map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like

```dart
void main() {
  Map<String, String> vaccinated = {
    'dog': 'ready',
    'cat': 'ready',
    'mouse': 'done',
    'horse': 'done',
  };

  final total =
      vaccinated.entries.where((e) => e.value == "done").toList().length;

  print(total);
}
```

More about [Map](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/Map-class.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can fold the values of the map to get the count.

```
Map<String, String> vaccinated = {
  'dog': 'ready',
  'cat': 'ready',
  'mouse': 'done',
  'horse': 'done',
};

int count = vaccinated.values.fold(0, (value, current) => value + (current == 'done' ? 1 : 0));
print(count);
```

Check out the fold method: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/fold.html